# Sending the value of a DIV into an SQL table when clicked

Tags: php, sql, survey

I have some trouble **retrieving the value assigned to my DIVs**. The DIVs contains answers to a survey. (I can't use other inputs such as select, radio button)

Below is the form:

```
<form id='Form01' action=''>    
<div class="box" id='input01' onclick="submit_answer()" value='1'>YES</div>                                     
<div class="box" id='input02' onclick="submit_answer()" value='2'>NO</
</form>
```

Below is the function to retrieve the answers:

```
function submit_answers(e) {
    OPTION1: var answer = $(#input01).attr('value'); // RETURNS "1" 
    OPTION2: var answer= $(this).attr('value');  // **RETURNS "Undefined"**
    console.log(answer) ;   
    $.post('input_answers.php',{value:answer});
}
```

**I'd like to insert '1' if the respondent clicks on "YES", '2' for "NO" but 
`var value01 = $(this).attr('value');` returns 'UNDEFINED.**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please don't do substantial edits as this causes answers that were originally correct to be incorrect (and therefore get downvotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```js
$("#input01,#input02").click(function(){
     var answer=  $(this).attr('value'); 

    console.log(answer) ;   
    $.post('input_answers.php',{value:answer});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='Form01' action=''>    
<div class="box" id='input01'  value='1'>YES</div>                                     
<div class="box" id='input02' value='2'>NO</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you both. I replaced click(function() as suggested by Brian and then used Jasinth hint to get all the values in only one line of code! Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things wrong with your code:

- You are not accessing the HTML element that fired the click.
- Value is an attribute on input elements (which a div is not).

To fix your JS correctly (and keep your use of jQuery) try the following:

```
function submit_answers(e) {
    var value01 = $(this).attr('value');
    $.post('input_answers.php',{value:value01});
}
```

Other issues I note with your code:

- There are multiple HTML with the same HTML id. "id" should be a unique identifier (consider using the class attribute if you are using it for styling or attaching JavaScript events)
- Another type of input would be better. Consider using radio buttons or select as this allows easier accessiblity
- Using the onclick HTML attribute is frowned on by most web developers - consider attaching events by JavaScript (eg using jQuery's .on or vannila JS's element.addEventListner())

**EDIT: after updated question**
As the JavaScript and HTML have changed substantially since my initial answer. Further issues are:

- The function specified in the onclick attribute and the function written in the JS section do not match.
- When defining answer in option 1, quotes are needed around #input01 (this is incorrect anyway as it is will always select the first div)
- The selector might need to e.target.

Issues fixed in the (substantial) edit:

- Duplicate id's
- Value is not a JavaScript attribute on a non-input elements

Comment: Hi Brian - I have updated and simplified my code example but it still does not catch the value of the answers unless I specify #input01 (cf. OPTION1)